# spring cloud feign hystrix fallback not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, hystrix, feign

same code with spring boot version 1.3.8.RELEASE and cloud version 'Brixton.SR' works right.
but '1.5.2.RELEASE' and 'Dalston.RC1' not work.

exception

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: math-service

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post so that we could help you better.

Comment: Can you provide a sample project demonstrating it not working?

Answer (score 16):

OK, you can add the following to your application.properties, then it works.

`feign.hystrix.enabled=true`

See [Dalston Release note](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Dalston-Release-Notes) and [Disable HystrixCommands For FeignClients By Default](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1277), Feign clients no longer wrap methods in Hystrix commands by default . You must have Hystrix on the classpath and also set feign.hystrix.enabled=true to have Feign automatically wrap methods in Hystrix commands.